# Retrofit Cache Data for Offline Usage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am using Retrofit library to parse and populate JSON data into RecyclerView.

But, Now I would like to know, How could I store same data for Offline usage, (even Internet is not available).

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        subscription = sampleAPI.getSamples()
                .cache()
                .timeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retry(1)
                .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Called unsubscribe OnPause()");
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<SampleTypePojo>() {
                               @Override
                               public void call(SampleTypePojo jokesModel) {
                                   sampleList = jokesModel.getValue();

                                   displaySampleList(sampleList);

                               }
                           }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                               @Override
                               public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                   Log.e(getClass().getName(), "ERROR: " + throwable.getMessage());
                                   throwable.printStackTrace();

                               }
                           }
                );
    }

    private void getSampleData() {
        if (sampleAPI == null) {
            sampleAPI = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .build()
                    .create(SampleAPI.class);
        }
    }
```

**app level:** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.4'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
}
```

Comment: using sqlite db

Comment: u can use sql  lite or relm database

Comment: I believe way is available to cache data for offline usage in Retrofit itself...

Comment: [A video recap](https://caster.io/episodes/retrofit-2-offline-cache/) for what you want to get.

Answer (score 13):

Let’s first build a OKHTTP client with

a cache
an interceptor that checks for connectivity and if none asks for cached data:
Here’s the client.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
  .Builder()
  .cache(new Cache(App.sApp.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
  .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Request request = chain.request();
      if (App.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
      } else {
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).build();
      }
      return chain.proceed(request);
    }
  })
  .build();
```

We first create the cache object with 10 MB, getting the cache directory from a static Application context.

Then the Interceptor uses a utility method in my Application class to check for connectivity. If there is connectivity, we tell the request it can reuse the data for sixty seconds.

If there’s no connectivity, we ask to be given only (only-if-cached) ‘stale’ data upto 7 days ago.

Now make this OkHTTP client your client for Retrofit2 and you will be able to use your old cached data when the app goes offline

Comment: Nice... well explained, no confusions, no doubts in my mind, except where I need to use this code in my app... and do I need to update to Retrofit 2.0 instead of 1.9 in build.gradle... please check above posted code and gradle sheet of mine and let me know your suggestions.

Comment: If we are saving data for 60 seconds then how data will be available after 60 seconds in case offline ? won't it delete automatically after 60 seconds from cache ?